# How to read map parquet file to case class for reading

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have the following type in `rdd`

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), (Array[Byte], Boolean))]
```

I wrote my `rdd` into parquet

```
val myDf = spark.createDataFrame(myRdd).toDF("id", "vals")

myDf.write.parquet("./myParquetDir")
```

Now I want to retrieve it

I see that it has the following form

```
Parquet form:
message spark_schema {
  optional group myId {
    optional binary _1 (UTF8);
    optional binary _2 (UTF8);
  }
  optional group myVal {
    optional binary _1;
    required boolean _2;
  }
}

Catalyst form:
StructType(StructField(myId,StructType(StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,StringType,true)),true), StructField(myVal,StructType(StructField(_1,BinaryType,true), StructField(_2,BooleanType,true)),true))
```

So I created

```
case class MySchema(
  myId: (String, String),
  myVal: (Array[Byte], Boolean)
)

val myParquetFileDf = spark.read.parquet("./myParquetDir")
val myParseDf = myParquetFileDf.as[MySchema].map( row=>
    println(row)
    row
).show(1, false)
```

But got an error

```
 org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<myId:struct<_1:string,_2:string>,myVal:struct<_1:binary,_2:boolean>> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
```

I don't understand, shouldn't the df schema map exactly to my rdd type?

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: does `myParquetFileDf.as[((String, String), (Array[Byte], Boolean))]]` work?

Comment: thanks, it worked, btw I am curious, is there cleaner way of doing the job?